# DB Error: no such field -- for new contribution page

Tags: civicontribute, contributions

Trying to create a New Contribution page, this is the message I get: 
"Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. 
DB Error: no such field"

Doesn't seem to matter what choices, options, or data I might enter on the page where I create a new Contrib page -- it always gives me this error. Don't know where to look next.

CiviCRM version 5.20.0

Drupal version 7.69 - Profile civicrm_starterkit

** CiviCRM ERROR MESSAGE**

Jan 09 13:36:55  [error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => exceptionHandler
        )

```
[code] => -19
[message] => DB Error: no such field
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => SELECT a.id as `id`, a.title as `title`, a.intro_text as `intro_text`, a.financial_type_id as `financial_type_id`, a.payment_processor as `payment_processor`, a.is_credit_card_only as `is_credit_card_only`, a.is_monetary as `is_monetary`, a.is_recur as `is_recur`, a.is_confirm_enabled as `is_confirm_enabled`, a.recur_frequency_unit as `recur_frequency_unit`, a.is_recur_interval as `is_recur_interval`, a.is_recur_installments as `is_recur_installments`, a.adjust_recur_start_date as `adjust_recur_start_date`, a.is_pay_later as `is_pay_later`, a.pay_later_text as `pay_later_text`, a.pay_later_receipt as `pay_later_receipt`, a.is_partial_payment as `is_partial_payment`, a.initial_amount_label as `initial_amount_label`, a.initial_amount_help_text as `initial_amount_help_text`, a.min_initial_amount as `min_initial_amount`, a.is_allow_other_amount as `is_allow_other_amount`, a.default_amount_id as `default_amount_id`, a.min_amount as `min_amount`, a.max_amount as `max_amount`, a.goal_amount as `goal_amount`, a.thankyou_title as `thankyou_title`, a.thankyou_text as `thankyou_text`, a.thankyou_footer as `thankyou_footer`, a.is_email_receipt as `is_email_receipt`, a.receipt_from_name as `receipt_from_name`, a.receipt_from_email as `receipt_from_email`, a.cc_receipt as `cc_receipt`, a.bcc_receipt as `bcc_receipt`, a.receipt_text as `receipt_text`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.footer_text as `footer_text`, a.amount_block_is_active as `amount_block_is_active`, a.start_date as `start_date`, a.end_date as `end_date`, a.created_id as `created_id`, a.created_date as `created_date`, a.currency as `currency`, a.campaign_id as `campaign_id`, a.is_share as `is_share`, a.is_billing_required as `is_billing_required`, a.frontend_title as `frontend_title`
```

FROM civicrm_contribution_page a
WHERE (a.id = "1")
LIMIT 25
OFFSET 0
[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.frontend_title' in 'field list']
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT a.id as `id`, a.title as `title`, a.intro_text as `intro_text`, a.financial_type_id as `financial_type_id`, a.payment_processor as `payment_processor`, a.is_credit_card_only as `is_credit_card_only`, a.is_monetary as `is_monetary`, a.is_recur as `is_recur`, a.is_confirm_enabled as `is_confirm_enabled`, a.recur_frequency_unit as `recur_frequency_unit`, a.is_recur_interval as `is_recur_interval`, a.is_recur_installments as `is_recur_installments`, a.adjust_recur_start_date as `adjust_recur_start_date`, a.is_pay_later as `is_pay_later`, a.pay_later_text as `pay_later_text`, a.pay_later_receipt as `pay_later_receipt`, a.is_partial_payment as `is_partial_payment`, a.initial_amount_label as `initial_amount_label`, a.initial_amount_help_text as `initial_amount_help_text`, a.min_initial_amount as `min_initial_amount`, a.is_allow_other_amount as `is_allow_other_amount`, a.default_amount_id as `default_amount_id`, a.min_amount as `min_amount`, a.max_amount as `max_amount`, a.goal_amount as `goal_amount`, a.thankyou_title as `thankyou_title`, a.thankyou_text as `thankyou_text`, a.thankyou_footer as `thankyou_footer`, a.is_email_receipt as `is_email_receipt`, a.receipt_from_name as `receipt_from_name`, a.receipt_from_email as `receipt_from_email`, a.cc_receipt as `cc_receipt`, a.bcc_receipt as `bcc_receipt`, a.receipt_text as `receipt_text`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.footer_text as `footer_text`, a.amount_block_is_active as `amount_block_is_active`, a.start_date as `start_date`, a.end_date as `end_date`, a.created_id as `created_id`, a.created_date as `created_date`, a.currency as `currency`, a.campaign_id as `campaign_id`, a.is_share as `is_share`, a.is_billing_required as `is_billing_required`, a.frontend_title as `frontend_title`
FROM civicrm_contribution_page a
WHERE (a.id = "1")
LIMIT 25
OFFSET 0
[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.frontend_title' in 'field list']
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: no such field" code=-19 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="SELECT a.id as `id`, a.title as `title`, a.intro_text as `intro_text`, a.financial_type_id as `financial_type_id`, a.payment_processor as `payment_processor`, a.is_credit_card_only as `is_credit_card_only`, a.is_monetary as `is_monetary`, a.is_recur as `is_recur`, a.is_confirm_enabled as `is_confirm_enabled`, a.recur_frequency_unit as `recur_frequency_unit`, a.is_recur_interval as `is_recur_interval`, a.is_recur_installments as `is_recur_installments`, a.adjust_recur_start_date as `adjust_recur_start_date`, a.is_pay_later as `is_pay_later`, a.pay_later_text as `pay_later_text`, a.pay_later_receipt as `pay_later_receipt`, a.is_partial_payment as `is_partial_payment`, a.initial_amount_label as `initial_amount_label`, a.initial_amount_help_text as `initial_amount_help_text`, a.min_initial_amount as `min_initial_amount`, a.is_allow_other_amount as `is_allow_other_amount`, a.default_amount_id as `default_amount_id`, a.min_amount as `min_amount`, a.max_amount as `max_amount`, a.goal_amount as `goal_amount`, a.thankyou_title as `thankyou_title`, a.thankyou_text as `thankyou_text`, a.thankyou_footer as `thankyou_footer`, a.is_email_receipt as `is_email_receipt`, a.receipt_from_name as `receipt_from_name`, a.receipt_from_email as `receipt_from_email`, a.cc_receipt as `cc_receipt`, a.bcc_receipt as `bcc_receipt`, a.receipt_text as `receipt_text`, a.is_active as `is_active`, a.footer_text as `footer_text`, a.amount_block_is_active as `amount_block_is_active`, a.start_date as `start_date`, a.end_date as `end_date`, a.created_id as `created_id`, a.created_date as `created_date`, a.currency as `currency`, a.campaign_id as `campaign_id`, a.is_share as `is_share`, a.is_billing_required as `is_billing_required`, a.frontend_title as `frontend_title`
FROM civicrm_contribution_page a
WHERE (a.id = "1")
LIMIT 25
OFFSET 0
[nativecode=1054 ** Unknown column 'a.frontend_title' in 'field list']"]
)

Comment: Can you check CiviCRM log file for more detail of db error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade or install script was suppose to create frontend_title field in civicrm_uf_group table. Did you get any error while doing upgrade or install?

To fix you will need to manually add the 'frontend_title' field to the table by running below sql query.

```
ALTER TABLE `civicrm_uf_group` ADD  `frontend_title` VARCHAR(64) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Profile Form Public title';

ALTER TABLE `civicrm_uf_group` ADD  `add_cancel_button` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Should a Cancel button be included in this Profile form.';
```

Comment: Problem solved! All I needed to do was to run the civicrm upgrade script again, and the tables were correctly created. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: So you mark this as answered if it was useful for you and think this going to help someone

Comment: My question has been answered, and I am happy and grateful for the help. But I don't see how to mark this as "answered". What do I do?